# Remove trailing 0s and last 1 from list of observations in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe (df) that looks similar to this:

| person | outcome |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| a | 1 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| a | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 1 |
| c | 0 |
| c | 0 |
| c | 0 |

For persons whose last observation is a 0, I would like to remove the trailing 0s plus the last 1, so that the final df looks like this:

| person | outcome |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 1 |
| b | 0 |
| b | 1 |
| c | 1 |

The last three 0s and last 1 were removed for A and C, but B was left alone because its last observation was a 1. Is there a way to do this, or does it have to be done by hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(person) %>% 
   mutate(new = cumsum(outcome)) %>%
   filter(if(last(outcome) == 0) new <max(new) else TRUE) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-new)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 2
  person outcome
  <chr>    <int>
1 a            1
2 b            1
3 b            0
4 b            1
5 c            1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(person = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"b", "c", "c", "c", "c", "c"), outcome = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-13L))
```

Comment: This is perfect! I was resigned to doing it by hand, thank you for your assistance!